# How to rename Order Total in Order Summary Sidebar?

Tags: magento2, cart, order-summary

I just tried with vendor folder -

```
 vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_cart_index.xml
```

line no 163 - I renamed the title.

But it is not reflecting.

Comment: Please share any other steps you took like clearing cache, etc.

Comment: I have cleared cache, removed pub/static folder except .htaccess. I run the deploy command also.

Answer (score 1):

magento\module-tax\view\frontend\layout\checkout_cart_index.xml